# How to use UnCSS

Tags: css, node.js, optimization, npm

I want to remove unused CSS classes on my site for that, I have installed UnCSS with `npm install -g uncss` command. But I don't know how to scan all HTML files in it with NPM script. Please help me.

Comment: You need https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom as described in HOW TO USE  here: https://github.com/uncss/uncss#how

Comment: jsdom already comes into the uncss package

Answer (score 2):

You can do it on terminal with:

`uncss -s dirty.css file.html > clean.css`

- the dirty.css is the stylesheet which contains unwanted/ unused styles.
- file.html is the page you test against.
- clean.css is the output from uncss, which you can changes as you want.

Comment: for multiple html files use uncss -s dirty.css file.html  file2.html > clean.css